# Add a background image to Site Page that stretches to fill the background

Tags: 2010, css, html

I am working in SharePoint 2010. I want to show a background image on the home page, that stretches to fill the entire content area. I have this in a Content Editor web part:

```
<style>
.bgimg {
  background: url(/SiteAssets/Gosport.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

And then this in the body of the page:

```
<div class="bgimg">
* All of my web parts *
</div>
```

I have it mostly working, my image is shown behind all the other web parts. But it doesn't stretch to fill the space. I have tried several examples online that would work on a regular HTML page, but I think SharePoint is interfering with the background size.

I have also tried this, it shows the image, but doesn't stretch:

```
<style>
.bgimg {
  background: url(/SiteAssets/Gosport.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue was IE 11, not SharePoint. This works for my Content Editor Web Part:

```
<style>
.bgimg {
  background: url(/SiteAssets/Gosport.png) no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
  src='/SiteAssets/Gosport.png',
  sizingMethod='scale');    
}
</style>
```